# Syncronization SQL Server databases which are placed remotely

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, synchronization

I have two SQL Server databases located at different locations. And I have to synchronize data between these two databases.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified how..you can use below technologies

**If both computers are in Same domain:**

1. Always on
2. Log shipping
3. Mirroring
4. Replication

**If both computers are not  in Same domain:**

1. Logshipping
2. Mirroring
3. Replication

I you do some research on above HA technologies, they do things differently and can serve your purpose

Comment: sir the databases are located for example different countries then how can do synchronize ?

Comment: Are they part of same domain ?

Comment: how ? sir can you guide me because i am newly learner . have you any tutorial any sample project ?